# Resize canvas element when parent changes its width/height

Tags: javascript, canvas

In my application I have a div with a canvas element inside it that display an image. The application also has a sidebar that can be hidden by clicking a button, and all the other elements should resize themselves to take the empty remaining space.

This works well for divs and other elements that have a width/height set to percents, but not for the canvas element.

This is the div I have:

```
<div id="background-img" class="image-div"></div>

.image-div {
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

where the height is initially 305px but it changes to 375px when the sidebar is hidden.

This is the canvas creation code:

```
const imgDiv = document.getElementById('background-img');
if (imgDiv) {
  const blob = new Blob([svg], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.className = 'canvas-background';
  canvas.id = 'canvas-id';
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.width = imgDiv.clientWidth;
  canvas.height = imgDiv.clientHeight;

  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  };
  img.src = url;
  imgDiv.appendChild(canvas);
}
```

and the canvas has no additional css defined anywhere.

How can I make it possible for the canvas to resize itself as soon as the parent changes his width and height (I am trying to make this resize work also when I zoom in/out the page like you do it in chrome for example, something that works with divs or img elements).

Comment: Can't you just add something along the lines of `canvas { width: 100% }`, then perhaps also a resize listener if you want to also update the canvas's internal pixel width (rather than display width which is determined by the CSS)

Comment: Does hidng the sidebar trigger a js event? if so why not use that event to resize the canvas also?

Comment: Looks like setting only the width and the height of the canvas.style, along with the width and the height of canvas that I did in my code did the trick. Now it resizes everywhere (and I don't see any significant quality loss, if any, in my use case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is not (yet) a good way to do this. Instinctively you would look for a `resize` event on an element. But that can only be applied to the `window` as [explained here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event).

After doing some research and looking at other threads I found a couple of options for you to consider.

**Continuous loop**

Draw the image in a recursive function which will also check the `imgDiv`'s width and height every time it draws itself.

CSS:

```
canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
function draw(ctx, imgDiv, img) {
    ctx.canvas.width = imgDiv.offsetWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = imgDiv.offsetheight;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        draw(ctx, imgDiv, img);
    });
}

img.onload = function() {
    draw(ctx, imgDiv, img);
};
```

This option has the benefit of checking all the time it can, but I image it can be quite heavy in terms of performance. `requestAnimationFrame` does improve performance by firing the function only when it is allowed in the speed of the framerate. So about  60 times per second on average.

**`ResizeObserver` (Warning: experimental technology)**

This is one I have not seen anywhere yet. The [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) is new and is in the family of the `IntersectionObserver`, `PerformanceObserver` and `MutationObserver`. Like the name suggests it observers changes in elements that are resized and fires a callback when it detects a change.

It works like this:

```
const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        // Update the canvas dimensions. 
    });
});

// Observer the image-div when it resizes.
observer.observe(imgDiv);
```

Since it is experimental I wouldn't recommend using it, although it would perfectly fit your scenario. More on browser support for this API her on [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=resizeobserver) and an article on how to use it from [Alligator.io](https://alligator.io/js/resize-observer/).

**Use the `resize` event on `window`**

This would only capture the scenario of changing the width of the window or document. And in case of your sidebar opening and closing it would need some extra tinkering.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', (event) => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        // Update the canvas dimensions. 
    });
});
```

Using `requestAnimationFrame` here is recommended since the `resize` event will be called on every pixel and can slow down performance.

**Edit:**

It seems that Artyomska solved the problem already. And although the issue is resolved I still want to share my research in case a future query may stumble on this thread.

Comment: Since the research is useful, even if you solved the problem after I found a solution I will still approve this as correct response for the research (and since the ones who added comments cannot be marked as a response :/ ). I think I can improve the solution with the performance code you added.